# Google play store 505 error while installing the app?

Tags: android

[Play store 505 error message while installing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkY1Q.jpg)

Anyone have any idea why i am getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried Google your problem ? Take a look at this: http://appslova.com/android-fix-unknown-error-code-application-install-505-error-505/

Comment: Yes... I already googled a lot... I tried that link too, but i just want to know that it's app issue or google play services issue?